# TestFlight applications: Is there a way to delay execution until the user selects "Start Testing"?

Tags: ios, swift, app-store-connect, testflight

For an iOS app running in Beta through TestFlight, users accepting an invitation for the first time are presented with a TestFlight modal on first load, that has a message from the developer and another screen that has a button to "Start Testing" (and close the modal).

The app does a couple things at startup, like request permissions. The permission alerts will present over this modal, and I would like to conditionally delay that until the modal is closed.

Is this possible?

Comment: Best practice is to request permissions when the user actually does something that needs the permission so that they have some context rather than just bombarding them with permission requests as soon as they launch the app

Comment: That's a fact, but our entry screen is a map that requires location permissions, so it happens right away.

Comment: Make the code to request permissions execute after the user clicks 'Start Testing'.. and then you probably need to reload the map afterward.

Comment: @purebreadd Thats what I'm asking how to do. If you know how I will accept your answer

Comment: You didn't post any code so idk what to tell you haha. Take the snippet of code that requests permissions, make it its own function, call it after 'start testing' is pressed. Recall any map annotations as needed.

Comment: @purebreadd The whole question is clearly asking how to tell that the user has clicked started testing. I'm not asking you how to ask for permissions. If there is a delegate method that gets called, please share it.

Comment: @purebreadd Let's pretend I want to call print("Yay they started testing") when they tap that button. Is that enough code for you to work with?

Comment: Hold on, you realize that I didn't code the "Start Testing" button right? The modal is built into TestFlight...

Comment: Sorry I thought Start Testing was a button you created. I've distributed Beta apps via TestFlight before and never have seen this modal popup. Maybe it's something you can turn off? Otherwise, maybe before requesting permission, you can check what the top view controller is and only present if it is the map view controller?

Comment: That's actually a good idea, I will try it out. Thanks

Comment: Did you find the answer @rolf